# Crystal Reports: Display only the value I want

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am working on a report that I am trying to display the value that I only want to show. Based on a formula, the report displays the value if the criteria is true, else zero. The report currently shows:

```
01(group number)
True  170
False   0
False   0

02
False   0
False   0
True  185
```

What I want is to move the "true" number next to the group number on the report. So it will show:

```
01(group number)   170 
02                 185
```

The field does not show up in the summary option because the formula contains the sum function.

Comment: if only true lines have a value ands there is only one true value per group you could use the sum of the group

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to mention that the formula contains a sum function. So the field does not show up in the summary option.